# Django and Java Applet authorization failed

Tags: java, django, applet, session-cookies

I'm building a Django App with **allauth**.

I have a page, with authentication required, where I put a Java applet. This applet do GET requests to other pages (of the same django project) which return Json objects.

The applet gets the **CSRF** token from the parent web page, using **JSObject**.

The problem is that I want to set ALL the pages with authentication control, but I cannot get the **sessionid** cookie from the parent web page of the applet, so it cannot do GET (and neither POST) to obtain (or save) data.

Maybe it is a simple way to obtain this, but I'm a newby, and I haven't found anything.

Ask freely if you need something.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Has I wrote downstairs, I found out that the **sessionid** cookie is marked as *HTTPOnly*, so the problem now is which is the most safe way to allow the applet to do POST and GET request.
For example it is possible to create a JS method in the page, which GET the data and pass it down to the applet?
Maybe in the same way I can do the POST?

EDIT:

I successfully get the data, using a jquery call from the page. The problem now is that the code throws an *InvocationTargetException*. I found out the position of the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is the Jquery code:

```
  function getFloor() {

        $.get(
              "{% url ... %}",
              function(data) {
                    var output = JSON.stringify(data);
                    document.mapGenerator.setFloor(output)
              }
        );}
```

And here there are the two functions of the applet. 
The ** part is the origin of the problem.

```
  public void setFloor(String input) {
    Floor[] f = Floor.parse(input);
}

  public static Floor[] parse(String input) {

    **Gson gson = new Gson();**

    Floor[] floors = gson.fromJson(input, Floor[].class);

    return floors;
}
```

And HERE is the log that come out on my server, where you can see that the applet try to load the Gson's library from the server (instead from the applet)

```
  "GET /buildings/generate/com/google/gson/Gson.class HTTP/1.1" 404 4126
```

Somebady can help me?

Comment: Now, for testing purpouse, I'm passing the value of **sessionid** in a custom session value, but I don't think it's the most sicure method to do this...

Comment: Do you have the option of  disabling CSRF middleware ? In place you can roll out a custom made middleware.

Comment: The problem is not csrf but sessionid. In every case, I decided to load the data for the applet when it's instantiate, using a session value.
During my tests I haven't found any security problems using the JQuery GET function. And so I will use to POST the results.

Comment: It's unlikely that `new Gson()` is throwing the exception, it's more likely the next line (Gson doesn't know how to covert to Floor[]). If it is the line you indicated it might be that you are not including the Gson jar file in your applet tag (in the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your applet:

```
String cookies = JSObject.getWindow(this).eval("document.cookie").toString();
```

This will give you all the cookies for that page delimited by semicolons.

Comment: It's not working. The problem here is that the cookie is marked *HTTPOnly*, so it's "impossible" to get it from Java or Js.

Comment: lol. So you're trying to get around your own security? Why not have the applet make a request to the server again so it can get a CSRF token directly? Otherwise you're basically trying to circumvent your own security.

Comment: :P Unfortunately I found out only now about this issue.
No, now I'm not trying to circumvent my server, but a way to solve this problems withouth using csrf or sessionid.

Comment: I have opened another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546506/java-applet-cannot-parse-json
because it's seems to be a more complex problem.