# Java Applet cannot parse Json

Tags: java, exception, applet, noclassdeffounderror, japplet

I'm developing a web server in Django, and in a page, I embed a Java Applet.

I have to pass to this applet a JSon array at the moment of instantiation. NO problems at all, I've tested it in Eclipse with no errors or problems.

The big problems came out when I put this on the web page.

First I tried with [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), here is the code on the page:

```
  <applet name="mapGenerator"
            id="mapGenerator"  
            code="main.MapGenerator.class"
            archive="{{STATIC_URL}}jar/MapGenerator.jar, 
                            {{STATIC_URL}}jar/plugin.jar
                            {{STATIC_URL}}jar/jackson-annotations-2.1.1.jar,
                            {{STATIC_URL}}jar/jackson-core-2.1.1.jar,
                            {{STATIC_URL}}jar/jackson-databind-2.1.1.jar"
                     >
                    <param name=id value="{{building.id}}">
                    <param name=piani value='{{floors}}'>  
            MAYSCRIPT
    </applet>
```

The Java code for parsing the Json:

```
  public static  Floor[] parse(String input, URL codebase) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
    BaseFloor[] bfloors=null;

        try {
              bfloors = mapper.readValue(input, BaseFloor[].class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
          for (int i=0; i < bfloors.length; i++) {

        Floor f = new Floor(bfloors[i]);
        f.setCodeBase(codebase);
        floors[i] = f;
    }
    return floors;
}
```

And here it's the error that I get in the Java console when I try to use it in the web page:

```
  Exception in thread "thread applet-main.MapGenerator.class-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.<clinit>(VisibilityChecker.java:172)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:195)
at objects.Floor.parse(Floor.java:37)
at main.MapGenerator.loadParameters(MapGenerator.java:67)
at main.MapGenerator.start(MapGenerator.java:31)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1698)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:250)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:180)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 7 more
```

So I tought about some strange implementation problem, and I tried with [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

As before here is the web page code:

```
   <applet name="mapGenerator"
            id="mapGenerator"  
            code="main.MapGenerator.class"
            archive="{{STATIC_URL}}jar/MapGenerator.jar, 
                            {{STATIC_URL}}jar/gson-2.2.2.jar,
                            {{STATIC_URL}}jar/plugin.jar
                     >
                    <param name=id value="{{building.id}}">
                    <param name=piani value='{{floors}}'>  
            MAYSCRIPT
    </applet>
```

And the Java code:

```
  public static  Floor[] parse(String input, URL codebase) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    BaseFloor[] bfloors = gson.fromJson(input, BaseFloor[].class);

    Floor[] floors = new Floor[bfloors.length];

    for (int i=0; i < bfloors.length; i++) {

        Floor f = new Floor(bfloors[i]);
        f.setCodeBase(codebase);
        floors[i] = f;
    }
    return floors;
}
```

I don't get any error running the applet on Eclipse, but when I go testing on a web page... I get another error:

```
  java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:107)
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:84)
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:66)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:71)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:353)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter$1.create(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:48)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:353)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:794)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
at objects.Floor.parse(Floor.java:33)
at main.MapGenerator.loadParameters(MapGenerator.java:67)
at main.MapGenerator.start(MapGenerator.java:31)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1698)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
  Eccezione: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks)
```

Here is the class **BaseFloor** that I'm tryng to parse, it's in the same package of the static function:

```
  package objects;


  public class BaseFloor {

      public int numero_di_piano;
      public String link;
      public String bearing;

      public float getBearing() {
    return Float.parseFloat(bearing);
      }

      public int getFloor() {
    return numero_di_piano;
      }

      public String getLink() {
    return link;
      }

      public String toString() {
    return numero_di_piano + " " + bearing + " " + link;
      }
  }
```

And here is the JSON that I'm passing to the applet:

```
  [{"bearing": "354.00", "link": "/media/floors/Foto_del_63333991-02-2455618_alle_17_35_6.jpg", "numero_di_piano": 0}, {"bearing": "354.00", "link": "/media/floors/IMG_20111009_171138_7.jpg", "numero_di_piano": 1}]
```

I'm curious: is it a problem of my implementation of the code, or is it a problem of security, because my applet isn't signed so the reflection cannot be used?

If you need something, ask freely.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I've tried what you suggested @Nikita, and the error changed!

```
  java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkMemberAccess(SecurityManager.java:1662)
at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2157)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1790)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:593)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:421)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.memberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:243)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addMethods(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:442)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collect(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:232)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:142)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:81)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:11)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig.introspect(DeserializationConfig.java:507)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:326)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:143)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:342)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:2898)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2792)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1942)
at objects.Floor.parse(Floor.java:40)
at main.MapGenerator.loadParameters(MapGenerator.java:67)
at main.MapGenerator.start(MapGenerator.java:31)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1698)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
  Eccezione: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
```

Comment: *"..or is it a problem of security, because my applet isn't signed so the reflection cannot be used?"*  Check the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) for output.

Comment: Exception the same in both cases. Are you sure you pasted correct message for second case?

Comment: The output is the error that I showed up @Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to insert comma after `{{STATIC_URL}}jar/plugin.jar` in your page. May be java plugin ignores jackson-annotations.jar because of this and you get `NoClassDefFoundError`.
Here is a similar question: [NoClassDefFoundError JsonAutoDetect while parsing JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094300/webapp-noclassdeffound-jsonautodetect) and missing `jackson-annotations` caused the problem.

Comment: In every case, I resolved creating a JS function on the page, called by the JApplet, which loads the JSON data, parse it on-the-place and returns a JSObject to the JApplet.